# Use a custom volume name in GKE auto-provisioned PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using auto-provisioned volumes with PVC in Google Kubernetes Engine like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-test-pvc1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

And it's working fine.

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                   STATUS   VOLUME                                     ...
my-test-pvc1           Bound    pvc-75025c65-8770-49c9-9d85-9c8ed61a3862   ...
my-test-pvc2           Bound    pvc-85a6edfa-5890-4641-bfee-721d3efc0f74   ...
my-test-pvc3           Bound    pvc-532365ef-621d-4e80-9523-7a6ec520f16c   ...
```

The volumes are automatically provisioned with a `pvc-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-....` naming scheme.

**My question is:** is it possible to influence those `pvc-...` volume names somehow to make them more descriptive? So that I can see what the volumes are for when I look at them in the GCE console [compute/disks](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/disks) page.

I've tried adding `volumeName: my-test-pv1` to the PVC spec, but that breaks auto-provisioning, i.e. nothing is provisioned anymore.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  The disk names have the cluster name as the prefix so you can at least map disks to clusters.